# Why does IntelliSense say it cannot find DDRB definition when I added it to json and it can even let me peek the definition? Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense, avr

I have this simply `blinky.c` code for `AVR` microcontrollers. It compiles and run no problem. But Intellisense in my vscode is going kinda crazy

```c
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define LED_PIN 0

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void main()
{
    DDRB |= (1 << LED_PIN);
    while(1)
    {
        PORTB ^= (1 << LED_PIN);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

First I edited the `json` to add the needed paths:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/avr/include",
                "/usr/avr/include/avr"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-Wall "
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And it sees the functions etc, all but `DDRB` and `PORTB`:

[image: IntellisenseError]

But when I go to "Go to definition" it even lets me see it. So how come it gives me this IntelliSense error?

[image]

To be clear Im on Linux right now (Manjaro). I have installed all the needed libs for `avr`s thru `pamac` and they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. It is caused by the internals of the `avr/io.h` files. It includes a certain file with definitions based on `#define` of a given microcontroller in the source code. So when I do not specify the controller it won't `#include` it in `io.h` therefor it is not visible to IntelliSense, but compilation can see it because I specify it. So in order to make `io.h` include definitions we need. We have to tell it which controller we will be using. Like that:

```c
#define __AVR_ATmega328P__
```

So that now my code looks like this:

```c
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define LED_PIN 0
#define __AVR_ATmega328P__


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void main()
{
    DDRB |= (1 << LED_PIN);
    while(1)
    {
        PORTB ^= (1 << LED_PIN);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

You can clearly see it when you look up the `io.h` file:

```c
#if defined (__AVR_AT94K__)
#  include <avr/ioat94k.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT43USB320__)
#  include <avr/io43u32x.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT43USB355__)
#  include <avr/io43u35x.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT76C711__)
#  include <avr/io76c711.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT86RF401__)
#  include <avr/io86r401.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT90PWM1__)
#  include <avr/io90pwm1.h>
...
```

It's basically 500 lines of checking for which controller we are using. If you go to this file and with `ctrl+f` or something like that you can easily find how your controller is defined there and include it. This solves the problem because the `DDRB` and `PORTB` are now defined thanks to resolved pre-processor statements.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that because your compilation succeeds, your compiler defines that `__AVR_ATmega328P__` in some compiler option. Maybe in `-mmcu=<mcu>`.

When you define that in your source, it may get mixed up with those compiler options.

A "better" way would be that you setup your IntelliSense configuration file properly, so that it won't affect your compilation.

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        ...
        "defines": ["__AVR_ATmega328P__"],
        ...
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Comment: This fix worked for me, although now it's harder to switch between a "regular" Arduino (for easy testing) and an ATTINY (for in-system testing). But I can live with that :D

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem is to include `avr/io.h` and `avr/ioXXXXX.h`: Something like so....

```
[line 0] #include <avr/io.h>
[line 1] #include <avr/ioXXXXX.h>
```

Ofcourse you can use `#define __AVR_XXXXX__` instead of line 1 as shown in the `io.h` file:

```
#if defined (__AVR_AT94K__)
#  include <avr/ioat94k.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT43USB320__)
#  include <avr/io43u32x.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT43USB355__)
#  include <avr/io43u35x.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT76C711__)
#  include <avr/io76c711.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT86RF401__)
#  include <avr/io86r401.h>
#elif defined (__AVR_AT90PWM1__)
#  include <avr/io90pwm1.h>
```

.......